# Group a table by if there is is isnt a matching record in joined table?

Tags: mysql

I have a table listing invoices which we group on the year to total with the following

```
SELECT
  sum(totalValue/((100 + Vat)/100)) AS purchases ,
  year(invoice_date) AS invoiceyear
FROM invoices
GROUP BY year(invoice_date)
ORDER BY invoiceyear Desc;
```

WE also have a list of the invoice table includes a link to the SupplierID in a list of suppliers , the product table also includes a list of the links to supplierID

I need to group on weather or not the invoices were for stock orders or not, so I need to group on the fact that there is or is not a product with a matching supplierID

This is where Im getting stuck, when I run the join im stuck on how to group by if the supplierID field is null or not null ??

Also some invoices are for multiple products how do I ensure Im not creating multiple records in the invoice table ?

Comment: Can you provide the definitions of the tables and columns that you allude to, for suppliers and products?

Comment: give your schema.Use (http://sqlfiddle.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your SupplierID column is called `SupplierID` and that each table has an `id` column, here's an answer:

```
SELECT
    SUM(`totalValue` / ((100 + `Vat`)/100)) AS `purchases`,
    `order_type`,
    `invoice_year`
FROM (
    SELECT `i`.*,   
        IF(COUNT(`p`.`id`) = 0, 'custom', 'stock') AS `order_type`,
        YEAR(`i`.`invoice_date`) AS `invoice_year`
    FROM `invoices` AS `i`
    LEFT JOIN `products` AS `p` 
        ON `i`.`SupplierID` = `p`.`SupplierID`
    GROUP BY `i`.`id`
) AS `filtered`
GROUP BY `order_type`, `invoice_year`
ORDER BY `invoice_year` DESC
```

Explanation: in order to do this, you need to left join on the products table, grouping by invoice id.  A count of the product id will return 0 or > 0 if there is a matching product or not.

We're putting that in a subquery because we don't want the count of products compounding with the outer grouping, which would cause issues in your math if you have more than 1 product per invoice in some cases (i.e. there are many products with the same supplier id).

Comment: Note that this will only return a sum for those _without_ the supplier, not separate counts for those with and without.

Comment: Oops, I misread the question.  Modified the query so it'll do what he wants.

Comment: I had to add year(invoice_date) as invoiceYear, into the slect and again into the grouping but yes this worked :) thanks

Comment: I see... adjusted my answer to reflect the need to additinoally group on invoice_year.